# how to change buddypress user groups page permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, buddypress

i want to change the permalink of user groups page like this..

from  http://mywebsite.com/groups/   to  http://mywebsite.com/crews/

and  i have changed the user groups page from  .. Settings >> Buddypress >> Pages >> Users Group
but when i visit to mywebsite.com/crews/ ,.. i just see the a basic wordpress page ..not buddypress user groups entry page.. 
any help would be appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the group slug by adding this to your bp-custom.php file:

```
define( 'BP_GROUPS_SLUG', 'crews' );
```